# Data Standardisation for Neural Network in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I have built a multilayer perceptron neural network in SPSS 22. I try the same using **"neuralnet"** package in R, but the results are not desirable. 
SPSS standardises data before performing training and I am wondering:

1. Does "neuralnet" package perform any sort of standardization? I could not find in its guide.
2. According to SPSS guide [here](http://library.uvm.edu/services/statistics/SPSS22Manuals/IBM%20SPSS%20Neural%20Network.pdf), standardised process is done as below:

> Subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation, (x−mean)/s.

Is there an optimal function that can do this in R? Since the method is quite simple, I can implement the scaling by my own, but it might not be efficient since number of data elements and records are very large.

Or maybe should I use another neural network package like **"monmlp"**? that standardize data automatically?

Many thanks

Comment: You can use the `scale()` function for that, see ?scale

Comment: If you're not set on the `neuralnet` package, the `caret` package has a [`preProcess`](http://www.inside-r.org/node/86978), option which you can use with the `nnet` function

Comment: You could a lot of things as other comments suggest, but after all if you need or not standardized version of your data is a choice driven by research purposes. Anyway in any case if you have a variable `x` you can just standardize it by yourself with `xs <- (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be useful if you need to standardize multiple columns in a data frame (call it `foo`):

```
# Index of columns to standardize
cols <- c(1,2,3,4)

# Standardize
library(plyr)
standardize <- function(x) as.numeric((x - mean(x)) / sd(x))
foo[cols] <- plyr::colwise(standardize)(foo[cols])
```

Comment: I got my work done and I am happy to accept it. However, there is one small issue here. This function standardizes the entire data frame as you said. If you can come up with a line that standardises selected fields, that would be general enough for novices too ;-)

Comment: also all data elements in foo should be numeric. You may consider putting as.numeric function too.

Comment: You can specify which columns by writing foo[c(1,2,3..)] instead of just foo.  You can also wrap standardize in as.numeric as you pointed out.

Comment: Ya, I did. but for future readers, they may not read below comments. Better to give them hint in the answer. ;-)

Comment: Do you have any idea on standardisation of date variable? When I change the date to numeric, it turn out a number and then I can standardize it, but it looks like incorrect.

Comment: Good point on changing the code in the answer.  Standardizing the date seems odd to me?  Is there a reason you want to do this?

Comment: ya, it is odd to me too. I used SPSS to model a customer behaviour. I kept making try and fail with varied variable and it turned out that their joining date is very much important. When I use this date, I get something like 95% detection success. So, I am wondering how to simulate it in R.